# I don't know why I'm getting a useEffect infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

```
 const handleLike = async () => {
    await likeTweet(tweet._id, user._id);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetch = async () => {
      const response = await fetchLikes(tweet._id);
      setTweetLikes(response.data);
      console.log("useEffect");
    };
    fetch();
  }, [handleLike]);
```

I'm just declaring the dependencies function, not excecuting it. I don't know why it's remounting the component

Comment: remove handleLike from the dependancy array

Comment: Are you defining `handleLike` inside the component itself?

Comment: you are depending your `useEffect` to a function. you should add your state to your dependency not a function.

Comment: @Lennholm Yes... is that bad? I'm really asking

Comment: Additionally, unless `handleList` returns a promise you don't need to `await` it, and you don't need to make the function `async`.

Comment: @Andy that function is making a request to the DB so the async is needed here. Thanks

Comment: @sebasosa Not in and of itself but you can't use such a function as a dependency. Since it gets redefined on every render cycle, it has a new identity every time which `useEffect` sees as a changed dependency, runs the effect which triggers a new render and you have your infinite loop.

Comment: @sebasosa ok, but the `await` is pointless if you're not awaiting the response for a reason. And you don't need `async` if you get rid of the `await`.

Comment: @Andy I'm awaiting the response because the request to the MongoDB database is asynchronous

Comment: @sebasosa but there's no code _after_ that `await`, and no return for from that function. Unless you're _also_ awaiting `handleLike` for some reason (your code doesn't show that) it doesn't need to be async.

Comment: @Andy You know what? You're right. I'm just adding info to the DB, I don;t need the response to do anything. Was so focused on the useEffect problem that I didn;t even remember what the request actually was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove `handleLike` from the dependency list. This is because, since you're setting the state inside the effect, the component will re-render. And this will run the function body again, which means that the `handleLike` function is defined again. And so the `useEffect` runs again.

Also, it seems like `handleLike` shouldn't be a dependency anyway, since you're not using it inside the effect.

If you must have it as a dependency, use the `useCallback` hook to prevent it from being redefined on every render.